Call an Isotope JavaScript method (Masonry layout) when using AJAX pagination
Quite new to Drupal. I have a News Article View that returns 10 news articles as masonry style news items (  https://www.okler.net/previews/porto/12.0.0/blog-masonry-3-columns.html and https://isotope.metafizzy.co) with a pager. I have the Views ajax enabled pager set to show 3 items at a time. When I try to page to 2|3.. I get a browser error stating:
isotope not initialized. Cannot call methods, i.e. $().isotope("layout") custom-plugins.js:312:1092
    r https://domain1.mysites.com/themes/custom/edsites_subtheme/assets/vendor/plugins/js/custom-plugins.js?sneqqg:312
    u https://domain1.mysites.com/themes/custom/edsites_subtheme/assets/vendor/plugins/js/custom-plugins.js?sneqqg:312
    jQuery 2
        each
        each
    u https://domain1.mysites.com/themes/custom/edsites_subtheme/assets/vendor/plugins/js/custom-plugins.js?sneqqg:312
    i https://domain1.mysites.com/themes/custom/edsites_subtheme/assets/vendor/plugins/js/custom-plugins.js?sneqqg:312
    build https://domain1.mysites.com/themes/custom/edsites_subtheme/assets/js/theme.js?sneqqg:4566

The Drupal 10 template that handles the pager is:
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a pager.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - items: List of pager items.
 *   The list is keyed by the following elements:
 *   - first: Item for the first page; not present on the first page of results.
 *   - previous: Item for the previous page; not present on the first page
 *     of results.
 *   - next: Item for the next page; not present on the last page of results.
 *   - last: Item for the last page; not present on the last page of results.
 *   - pages: List of pages, keyed by page number.
 *   Sub-sub elements:
 *   items.first, items.previous, items.next, items.last, and each item inside
 *   items.pages contain the following elements:
 *   - href: URL with appropriate query parameters for the item.
 *   - attributes: A keyed list of HTML attributes for the item.
 *   - text: The visible text used for the item link, such as "‹ Previous"
 *     or "Next ›".
 * - current: The page number of the current page.
 * - ellipses: If there are more pages than the quantity allows, then an
 *   ellipsis before or after the listed pages may be present.
 *   - previous: Present if the currently visible list of pages does not start
 *     at the first page.
 *   - next: Present if the visible list of pages ends before the last page.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_pager()
 */
#}
{% if items %}
  <nav aria-label="{{ heading_id }}">
    <h4 id="{{ heading_id }}" class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Pagination'|t }}</h4>
    <ul class="pagination js-pager__items">
      {# Print first item if we are not on the first page. #}
      {% if items.first %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="{{ items.first.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to first page'|t }}"{{ items.first.attributes|without('href', 'title') }} class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.first.text|default('«'|t) }}</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'First page'|t }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print previous item if we are not on the first page. #}
      {% if items.previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="{{ items.previous.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to previous page'|t }}" rel="prev"{{ items.previous.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }} class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.previous.text|default('‹'|t) }}</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Previous page'|t }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Add an ellipsis if there are further previous pages. #}
      {% if ellipses.previous %}
        <li class="page-item" role="presentation"><span class="page-link">&hellip;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Now generate the actual pager piece. #}
      {% for key, item in items.pages %}
        <li class="page-item {{ current == key ? 'active' : '' }}">
          {% if current == key %}
            <span class="page-link">
              {{- key -}}
            </span>
          {% else %}
            <a href="{{ item.href }}" title="{{ title }}"{{ item.attributes|without('href', 'title') }} class="page-link">
              {{- key -}}
            </a>
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
      {# Add an ellipsis if there are further next pages. #}
      {% if ellipses.next %}
        <li class="page-item" role="presentation"><span class="page-link">&hellip;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print next item if we are not on the last page. #}
      {% if items.next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="{{ items.next.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to next page'|t }}" rel="next"{{ items.next.attributes|without('href', 'title', 'rel') }} class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.next.text|default('›'|t) }}</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Next page'|t }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {# Print last item if we are not on the last page. #}
      {% if items.last %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="{{ items.last.href }}" title="{{ 'Go to last page'|t }}"{{ items.last.attributes|without('href', 'title') }} class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">{{ items.last.text|default('»'|t) }}</span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'Last page'|t }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
{% endif %}

The isotope plugin maker suggests the below fix (as per https://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq) but I don't know how/where to apply it.
$grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Isotope
  $grid.isotope({
    // options...
  });
  // isotope has been initalized, okay to call methods
  $grid.append( $items )
    .isotope( 'appended', $items );
});

I tried to add the below to the Drupal pager template with no success:
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
$grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Isotope
  $grid.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
  });
  // isotope has been initalized, okay to call methods
  $grid.append( $items )
    .isotope( 'appended', $items );
});
 });
</script>

The webpage source code is view-source:https://www.okler.net/previews/porto/12.0.0/blog-masonry-3-columns.html
Hopefully someone could advise how to call the $().isotope("layout") method when I page the pagination.
Thanks!

That you're putting JavaScript in a template suggests you are unfamiliar with the API. Reading Drupal's JavaScript API would be a good starting point for you: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview
